# How To Edit a Specfic Column Value of a Selected Row ONLY in Jquery dataTables

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, datatables

I have have a Datatable with following columns

```
var t = $('#myDataTable').DataTable({
    
    "scrollX": true,
    "scrollY": true,
 
    columnDefs: [
        {//ProductName
            targets: 0, className: 'text-left'
        },
        {//Code
            targets: 1, className: 'text-center'
        },
        {//Quantity
            "render": $.fn.dataTable.render.number(',', '.', 4), "targets": 2, className:'text-right'
        }
    ]
});
```

and the users can select the row by clicking anywhere on the row with the following code.

```
$('#myDataTable tbody').on('click', 'tr', function () {
if ($(this).hasClass('selected')) {
$(this).removeClass('selected');
}
else {
t.$('tr.selected').removeClass('selected');
$(this).addClass('selected');
}
});
```

what i am trying to achieve is when the user clicks on a Generate Draft Invoice (as shown in the attachment), the value in the quantity column will get updated from a 1234. only in the selected row. Not all the row.

this is what i was trying to do but it is not working :(

```
$('#GenerateDraftInvoice').click(function () {
    t.row('.selected').$(this).parents('tr').data()[4].text('1234');
});
```

Note: I have shortened my code for easy understanding.[When The User Clicks on The Generate Draft Invoice Button as show in the picture. The quantity value in the selected row (RowNo: 2) will get change to 1234. I have shortened my code for easy understanding of the reviewer.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qWEZJ.png)

Thanks in advance. Stay Safe :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assume that quantity is 3rd column.

```
$('#GenerateDraftInvoice').click(function () {
    $('tr.selected').children().eq(2).text('1234');
});
```

`.eq()` is start from `0` and `.data()` is using with attribute like `data-modal`

ps.Im not sure about position of GenerateDraftInvoice's Button but if its attached to row the code will change to

```
$('#GenerateDraftInvoice').click(function () {
    $(this).parent().siblings().eq(2).text('1234');
});
```

Comment: Thank you so much Pakawat, you saved my day, I spent a lot of time and researched over google and other sources but was not able to find this solution. anyhow; i am having some more queries on DataTables which i was wondering if you or some one you know can teach me, Please let me know of some one is interested.